# How to write redirections in .magento/routes.yaml (regex)?

Tags: magento2, cloud

Our site has two websites with different domains. For security reasons, we want to sanitize the URl which has  tags. I am not sure how to add a case insensitive redirection applicable for both domains for this scenario in routes.yaml through the regex.

**Example**:

Domain 1: *[www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com)*

Domain 2: *[www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com)*

I want the URLs which has  tag in it either in the path or as a query string to be redirected to the specific domain home page.

> [www.domain1.com/cms/\](http://www.domain1.com/cms/%5C)<script>     --->  **[www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com)**

> [www.domain2.com/test?\](http://www.domain2.com/test?%5C)<script>    --->  **www. domain2.com**

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Magento Cloud.  You really can't do that kind of redirect in the routes.yaml file.  It's not an effective place to do security filtering, and the redirect only looks at the domain and path, not query parameters, so it wouldn't be able to filter that part of the URL anyway.

Generally speaking, complex redirects should be implemented in the application, not at the routing level.  And filtering out HTML or JS from the URL shouldn't be handled by a redirect at all.

Comment: Do You have any solution on this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/91533/crell